# 1 item could not be synced. See iTunes for more information

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, app-store-connect

After creating an IPA build, i installed in my device and got an alert like "1 item could not be synced. See iTunes

for more information ".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And did you see iTunes for more information?

Comment: same issue, there was no additional info on iTunes :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this : https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3390697?start=75&tstart=0

https://discussions.apple.com/message/18707253#18707253.

You can get solution from these links.